# Network Size is 100Mbit/s, but my capacity is 1Gbit/s. I have I219-V Ethernet connection

Tags: networking, drivers, iwlwifi, lan

> My Network size is 100Mbit/s, and i wanna change it to 1Gbit/s, because my capacity is 1Gbit/s.

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno1
       version: 10
       serial: 04:92:26:c1:64:79
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.5-4 ip=192.168.0.23 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:128 memory:a0500000-a051ffff
```

> I tried to install the drivers *https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/15817*, but i found an error. When i run `make install`, this error happens:

*** The target kernel has CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL enabled, but
*** the signing key cannot be found. Module signing has been
*** disabled for this build.

Comment: No additional driver is needed. Maybe you need a proper cable?

Comment: Did you fix it? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your cable has the 802.3u standard: 2 twisted pair for 100mb. For Gigabit you'll need 4 twisted pairs, as defined in 802.3ab.

So this boils down to the following wiring:

- 100BASE-TX   100Mb/s     802.3u      2 pairs: pins 1,2,3,6
- 1000BASE-T   1000Mb/s    802.3ab     4 pairs: pins 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

Check the wiring of your cable

Comment: It have 4 pairs, and i have used it when i had windows 10 in my PC.